# Random characters in vim, Firefox

Tags: firefox, arch-linux, unicode

I've seen lots of posts talking about improper Unicode support, but I've not yet been able to find a post with this issue (could still be the Unicode problem though). I recently spun up my first Arch Linux VM and have been having a blast, but recently I've found myself getting weird characters such as this:

[image: Strange characters]

I'm running Arch Linux 4.7.6-1 in Virtualbox on an x86-64 machine. Not sure what other information is relevant -- let me know and I'll update the post accordingly!

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the gnu-free-fonts package from pacman.

```
sudo pacman -S gnu-free-fonts
```

Comment: So is it the gnu that gumming up the works?  gnu-free fonts don't have that problem?  :-)